# "Unable to determine VS Code version" - flutter doctor -v

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

[Unable to determine VS Code version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjqd6.png)

Hi,

With this error also flutter is working perfectly but I need to mark this issue also in green color tick. Therefore you can help me in this matter.

I really appreciate a solution without re installing the vs code.

Thanks!